# ZF2 - Not display zend validator messages under input element on validation failure

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I don't want to display Zend validator messages under input element on validation failure by default But I need Zend validation message as per my requirement.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution.
The solution is here.

I was using

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('username')); ?>
```

Now I have replaced this with

```
<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('username')); ?>
```

And to get the error message as per my requirement on view, I used

```
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('username')); // Errors must be capital letter
```

Thanks for the all responses.

Comment: You can either output errors on per element basis, as per default used by the `formRow()` or you can use it as you've pointed out in your question using `$form->getMessages()`. Didn't went into detail on per-element-rendering since I assumed you don't need it ;)

Comment: @Sam : My problem was that I was unable to remove the error messages coming under input element else is ok.

Answer (score 5):

sorry but your answer is not the answer to your inital question!

Your title asks for a general solution how to disable validation messages in the whole application and the solution for that is:

```
<?php
namespace YourApp;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow;

class Module
{
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'formRow' => function($sm) {
                    $helper = new FormRow();
                    $helper->setRenderErrors(false);
                    return $helper;
                }
            ),
        );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

First: do not use the `formCollection()`-ViewHelper

Second: render the form using the `formRow()`-ViewHelper and set the third parameter to false. You can see this here: [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow#157`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormRow.php#L157)

```
echo $this->formRow($element, $labelPosition, $renderErrors);
```

**`$element`** should be the form element to render, i.e.: `$this->form->get('elementName')`

**`$labelPosition`** can simply be set to null if you need the default value

**`$renderErrors`** is a bool value dictating if errors should be rendered or not